# Get a sublist using LINQ and select items depending on the timestamp

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of:

```
class test
{
    name,
    timestamp
}
```

and I'd like to get all the last (newest) tests that have the same name. Many tests have same timestamp.

Eg:

```
name1, 2012-10-25 3:00PM
name1, 2012-10-25 3:00PM
name2, 2012-10-25 3:05PM
name2, 2012-10-25 3:05PM
name1, 2012-10-25 3:10PM
name1, 2012-10-25 3:10PM
name2, 2012-10-25 3:15PM
name2, 2012-10-25 3:15PM
```

I only need to get the last tests for each name:

```
name1, 2012-10-25 3:10PM
name1, 2012-10-25 3:10PM
name2, 2012-10-25 3:15PM
name2, 2012-10-25 3:15PM
```

Comment: Is your second request, the one about timestamp, a different query from the first one?

Comment: Probably it's me, but I still don't understand what you need. Could you add some sample data and expected output?

Comment: Added sample data. I realized question wasn't clear. thanks

Comment: Thanks, clearer now, check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var q = from l in list
        group l by l.Name into g
        select new
        {
            Name = g.Key,
            Max = g.Max (x => x.Timestamp)
        } into x
        from y in list 
        where x.Name == y.Name && x.Max == y.Timestamp
        select y;
```

What happens here is first a grouping on `list` by `Name`, and doing that I select for each group the max `Timestamp`. This goes `into x`. Then I rejoin the same `list` to the grouped one, matching all the pairs from the grouping, this way I'm selecting all the original items matching the grouped items.

Comment: It works! I just don't understand how this simple task can translate into such complicated query :D

Comment: :) It's not complicated, I'll add some more details to the answer

Comment: Maybe using procedural linq it may look prettier

Comment: Not sure, query syntax has some limitations but, when not hitting them, is usually more readable.

Comment: Side note: IMO "procedural Linq" is not a good definition, you should call it "method chaining", or "fluent", but procedural is really distant from the "functional" way Linq introduces. Procedural implies side effects, steps, and specifying "how" doing things, "functional" (and Linq) are about declaring "what" you need, and avoid side effects.

Answer (score 1):

```
var groups = list.GroupBy(x => x.name)
                 .Select(x => new  test{ 
                    Name = x.Key, 
                    TimeStamp = x.Max(y => y.timestamp) 
                  })
                 .ToList();
```

Comment: Wouldn't `Max` get the largest timestamp, which would be the newest?

Comment: I'm getting a list of anonymous type with the name and the timestamp but I actually need the test objects.

Comment: @user1774914 I updated the answer, the only thing is you should do is creating  new `test` class.

Comment: Sorry I've just realized I meant newest.